# Java: How to assign to a variable if the result is null?

Tags: java, null

This works:

```
String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
```

...but i don't want to display "null". So i tried this, which does not work:

```
String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1") || "");
```

Is the best option to use this:?

```
String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
if (address1 == null) address1 = "";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
if (address1 == null || address1.equals("null")) {
    address1 = "";
}
```

Comment: Because the database also contained bad strings, i'll accept this answer.

Comment: If you have multiple variables you have to get from your ResultSet and you need to check for null (or "null"), I would suggest to write a method you can reuse for other variables and perhaps wrap this in a ResultSetWrapper so you keep your code clean.

Comment: I would also suggest your get rid of the "null" strings in your database / application. It is an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: That was actually a mistake (i didn't realize the escape function would not escape the null), but the field can contain whitespace and i always forget about having to use equals() to reliably compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 6):

Using *ternary operator*, you can assign a value with single line of code:

```
String address1 = (rs.getString("address1") != null) ?
                  HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1")) : "";
```

Comment: It's bad practice to make identical calls to a method (here, `rs.getString`); use a temporary variable instead.

Comment: @Vulcan I just wanted to give an idea to the OP. Of course he/she can use temporary variable for it. but this has nothing to do with the accuracy of my answer and you shouldn't have downvoted.

Comment: I like the ternary operator but in this case my solution is shorter, more readable, and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1")) == null ? "" : HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
```

If you want ugly one-liner:-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a temp variable to only call `HtmlUtil.escape` once. Then check for `null` and assign to `address1`:

```
String tempAddress =  HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
String address1 = tempAddress != null ? tempAddress : "";
```

Comment: I'd rather not create additional variables.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
 String address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
 if (address1 == null) address1 = "";
```

Comment: I suppose this is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<c:when test="${empty rs.getString("address1")}">
  ...
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
   .....
</c:otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
String address1 = "";
if(HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1") != null && !(HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1").equalsIgnoreCase("null"))){
address1 = HtmlUtil.escape(rs.getString("address1"));
}
```

Comment: You really don't have to call and escape thrice, but that does look like my final code: `if (address1 != null && address1 != "") address_tip += address1+"&#10;";`